# How can I evaluate a single hypothesis against multiple result sets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, optimization

I have a hypothesis: optimising a trading algorithm's parameters increases the final balance of a trader.

I have several sets of results that vary the environment trading occurs in, each of which I have a set of results for both the trader with optimisation, and a trader without optimisation.

Am I able to whether test a single hypothesis holds true for several sets of, potentially contradictory, results? Or would I need to split it into several hypotheses for each environmental case, for example:

H1 = optimising a trading algorithm's parameters increases the final balance of a trader when the initial parameters are X

H2 = optimising a trading algorithm's parameters increases the final balance of a trader when the initial parameters are Y

Thanks in advance